# how to add path effect to axis tick labels in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

trying to figure out how to add path effects to my axis tick labels in a plot.. I know how to do it for the axis label:

```
cb.set_label('Water Surface Elevation [m]', fontsize=18, path_effects=[pe.withStroke(linewidth=1, foreground="b")])
```

assuming `cb` is a `fig.colorbar` object and `pe` is `matplotlib.patheffects`

but cannot figure out for the tick labels? anybody know how? thanks
[image: figure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the argument `path_effects=[pe.withStroke(linewidth=1, foreground="b")]` to `cb.ax.set_yticklabels`. For example:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import patheffects as pe
from matplotlib import cm


# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(42)
# Make plot with vertical (default) colorbar

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

data = np.clip(randn(250, 250), -1, 1)

cax = ax.imshow(data, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
ax.set_title('Gaussian noise with vertical colorbar')

# Add colorbar, make sure to specify tick locations to match desired ticklabels
cb = fig.colorbar(cax, ticks=[-1, 0, 1])
cb.ax.set_yticklabels(['< -1', '0', '> 1', ], fontsize=18, path_effects=[pe.withStroke(linewidth=1, foreground="b")])  # vertically oriented colorbar

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: ah thanks fellow derek.. I was trying to do it through tick_params